# How get empty record on date field with entityQuery?

Tags: 8, database, entities

I am on a custom entity with custom fields and i try to get all empty record on date field :

Field was create with CCK, so the field storage has a table.

```
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('test_entity');
        $query->condition('field_date',NULL,'=');
        $ids=$query->execute();
```

This doesn't work for date field.

Comment: Have you looked in the DB and confirmed that the values for those columns are actually null and not something else? The column is text or integer, depending on which field type you selected, so as far as a database query goes, there's nothing special about comparing it to null

Comment: it's a field create with the drupal interface, so the field is in fact a table, she has no record

Comment: That'll be it then - the query will do an `INNER JOIN` on the field data table because you've included it in the conditions, and there's no data, so nothing to compare to null. Hence no results.

Comment: yes, so i replace with $query->notExists('field_date'); that seems to work, i ll try more test

Comment: Oh brilliant, they accounted for that situation this time round, good news. Please do put an answer on once you've confirmed that works, this will be useful to a lot of people in time

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since the field is stored in a single table, this is how i get all empty record from my entity where my custom field is empty :

```
 $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('test_entity');
        $query->notExists('field_date');
        $ids=$query->execute();
```

Comment: What about when it's in multiple tables?

Comment: you need to add more conditions, like id or another field for filter. But your first filter is your entity ( entityQuery('test_entity')

Comment: This is great for when you add a new field to a content type but you can't bulk save them all for some reason.

Comment: This is not working on a few fields. Any idea why it will behave like this?   $appeal_query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('status', 1)->condition('type', 'appeal')->notExists('field_appeal_country');

Comment: Just for the record, here's the documentation for exists/notExists : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/interface/QueryInterface/8.2.x