# Possible to use EntityStorageBase::loadByProperties() to specify that field is or is not empty?

Tags: 8, entities

Is there a way to use `EntityStorageBase::loadByProperties()` to specify that a field is either empty or not empty? I just want to check whether or not a `field_date_completed`has a value set one it.

Looking to do something like `$this->myEntityStorage->loadByProperties(['field_date_completed'=> notEmpty])` or `$this->myEntityStorage->loadByProperties(['field_date_completed'=> isEmpty])`

EDIT:
Sorted out a solution using the accepted answer. Per [How get empty record on date field with entityQuery?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217640/how-get-empty-record-on-date-field-with-entityquery), we can do something like

```
$query = $this->myEntityStorage
  ->getQuery()
  ->notExists('field_data_completed');

$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in a narrow scope where "empty" for the field means the empty string (`''`) and it's stored as such in the DB.

`EntityStorageBase::loadByProperties()` uses a helper method, [`::buildPropertyQuery()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AbuildPropertyQuery/8.8.x), that chains comparisons using the `IN` operator. As such, you can't use negation or special comparison cases (e.g. `IS NULL` if "empty" means `NULL` in the DB).

Unless you have simple string comparisons for your field, you're better off skipping `::loadByProperties()` and using [`EntityStorageBase::getQuery()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AgetQuery/8.8.x) to retrieve a query object that you can customize to fit a "empty" / "not empty" query.

Comment: Ah that's too bad. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any examples I might be able to reference for this?

Comment: Nevermind, sorted this out. Adding an example to an EDIT.