# Load nodes by property, including empty ones

Tags: 8, entities

I want to render a node with certain properties set. For example, I want to load every node which ONLY has field_a and the other fields are empty.

If I use

```
$this->nodeStorage->loadByProperties(['type' => 'node_type', 'field_a' => $value]);
```

-> this will load every node which has field_a, but the other fields are not necessarily empty. I tried setting all the other fields to null, but it throws an InvalidQueryException. How can I change that query to IS NULL or which function can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loadByProperties()` executes an entity query with `->condition()` for each property. You can't use this for empty fields, you need

```
$query->notExists('field_example');
```

according to [How get empty record on date field with entityQuery?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217640/how-get-empty-record-on-date-field-with-entityquery)